# Firebase React Native: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have this error: `[TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function]`.
I'm trying to update my user information in firestore and show an alert when done. When I click the button "save" it updates the information inside the firestore but it shows an error in the console.

`OnPress Activity on TouchableOpacity:`

```
onPress={async () => {
                            const updatedUser = await firestore()
                                .collection('Users')
                                .doc(currentUser.uid)
                                .update({
                                    'name': name,
                                })
                                .then(() => {
                                    Alert("Successfully updated!")
                                })
                                .catch((e) => {
                                    console.log(e);
                                });
                        }}
```

I've seen people have this error when they're trying to add GeoLocation, but I'm just trying to update user's name.
I tried to do it outside of the onPress, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the [`Alert` documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert), you have to invoke it like this:

```
Alert.alert("Successfully updated!", "")
```